# One activity that runs the whole time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, timer

I want to calculate how much time a user spends on my app. I thought of doing so by using chronometer. So is there an activity or something that runs always when the user is using any part of my app? or should i start and stop the timer in each and every activity?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the right way to do it.  Use Activity lifecycle callbacks (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) to determine when one of your activities is paused/resumed.  When one is resumed, start the timer.  When one is paused, end it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service` instead of `Activity`.
Services run in background and you can access them all the time.